# SqlException Timeout expired into Dot net core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

My website build with 4.1 nopcommerce platform. now I have update all the dll of this website to the latest. now it working fine in normal days but in some of time I get an error log regarding "SqlException: Timeout expired". now how to resolve this issue. I have reviewed many posts and many think changes i have made to resolve this issue but I can't find any solution.

Log detail as below

```
System.Exception: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Nop.Data.EfRepository`1.Insert(TEntity entity) in C:\\Libraries\Nop.Data\EfRepository.cs:line 100 ---> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Nop.Data.EfRepository`1.Insert(TEntity entity) in C:\\Libraries\Nop.Data\EfRepository.cs:line 100
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nop.Data.EfRepository`1.Insert(TEntity entity) in C:\\Libraries\Nop.Data\EfRepository.cs:line 105
   at Nop.Services.Customers.CustomerService.InsertGuestCustomer(Int32 storeId) in C:\\Libraries\Nop.Services\Customers\CustomerService.cs:line 446
   at Nop.Web.Framework.WebWorkContext.get_CurrentCustomer() in C:\\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\WebWorkContext.cs:line 250
   at Nop.Web.Framework.WebWorkContext.get_WorkingLanguage() in C:\\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\WebWorkContext.cs:line 360
   at Nop.Web.Framework.Globalization.CultureMiddleware.SetWorkingCulture(IWebHelper webHelper, IWorkContext workContext) in C:\\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Globalization\CultureMiddleware.cs:line 62
   at Nop.Web.Framework.Globalization.CultureMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IWebHelper webHelper, IWorkContext workContext) in C:\\Presentation\Nop.Web.Framework\Globalization\CultureMiddleware.cs:line 82
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , HttpContext , IServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<UseMiddleware>b__2(HttpContext context)
   at Nop.Services.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\\Libraries\Nop.Services\Authentication\AuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 79
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Nop.Core.Http.InstallUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IWebHelper webHelper) in C:\\Libraries\Nop.Core\Http\InstallUrlMiddleware.cs:line 51
   at Nop.Core.Http.KeepAliveMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IWebHelper webHelper) in C:\\Libraries\Nop.Core\Http\KeepAliveMiddleware.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: @PabloRecalde this error display another issue. my error is differs from your provided link

Comment: @PabloRecalde can you please remove the duplicate tag from this question because this describe the another issue

Comment: Have you tried setting the timeout to 0 on your connection string to see if it hangs forever or if it just gets slow?

Comment: Ok, I've done it.

Comment: @PabloRecalde I already try this one but i didn't get my solution. I know very well about this setting. even i have made many changes that i found from google but didnt get any solution.

Comment: @SangeetShah you didn't specify a *problem* to begin with. That error says your query took too long. Why? Did it try to insert 1M rows one by one? Did some other code execute a big query that locked the entire table? If you increase that timeout the query won't run faster. Timing out means that slow query won't bring down the server.

Answer (score 1):

> SqlException: Timeout expired

This error is very common in SQL Server, and when I take a look on your trace, seems you want to read data. If you want to fix this error, my answer is **it can't be FIXED PERMANENTLY**. Because? This exception depends on many factors such as Network (in case you deploy application and database in different servers), Workload when error occurs, how large data you read, etc.

In case you thought an old version is working better, so that a new version get a problem in handling Database Connection. I read that you use nopcommerce platform, that means it needs to be fixed somewhere in nopcommerce.

Then a good solution is tuning 1. Your query 2. Your database server, or if you aren't good in Database side, I suggest you apply Retry Pattern or breaking smaller data which you want to read.

Comment: I have check all think that u mention but i dint get any solution regarding this.

Comment: Are you checking how many records which are impacted by your query? If you aren't sure, you can log a executed query and try to execute its in your database (production)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error.

- Any deadlock issues on executed queries ?
- Have you reached the number of opened connections which is usually limited to 300 - 600 ?
  The database may return this error if the limit has been exceeded.